# How to change default tint color in Xcode interface builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

How does one change the global default tint color in Xcode interface builder?

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In the *File inspector* tab of the *Utility* panel, the right one, you can find controls about size classes, auto layout and the global tint of your storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Actually Global Tint is available in Storyboard only (doesn't have in Xib). But still useful. Thank Marco!

Comment: @nahung89 is right. Any way to set it for XIBs in Xcode, or must this be done programmatically?

Answer (score 5):

**Interface Builder Way**:
Select the Storyboard or Xib file you want to set the default tint on.

Then in Utilities on the first tab File Inspector look for the Interface Builder Document section and you will see a Global Tint like the image below shows.

(not enough reputation to post images)

[image]

**Programmatically**:

*Obj-C:*
    `[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];`

*Swift:*
`UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds).tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()`

Comment: Is there a possible way to do this on XIB's?? not showing for me on any, only on storyboards, using Xcode 12

Answer (score 2):

You can set default tint color for whole window:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        window?.tintColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to work if you turn on localization.  The Global Tint dissapears

Comment: Actually it's still there. You just have to select the storyboard within the enclosing grouping. (Click the triangle to the left of the storyboard in Xcode's file browser.)

Answer (score -1):

You can set the default appearance settings with:

```
UIButton.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
```

If you place it in:

```
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

and only it'll apply application wide. Unless you change it lower down in the chain i.e. in UIViewController's

```
viewDidLoad:
```