# How to set default tint color for XIB files in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xib

How does one set the default tint color for UI elements loaded into an app by means of a XIB file? I've [tried the method here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795512/how-to-change-default-tint-color-in-xcode-interface-builder), but that only applies the color to Storyboards, not XIBs. It'd be great to do so within interface builder, but I'd be fine setting it programmatically too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled on a solution which sets it for all XIBs too. In the UIApplicationDelegate put this line in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
    window?.tintColor = UIColor.orange
```